# How do I get an animation to play at the same time as a TextToSpeech utterance in Android

Tags: android

I have a set of buttons in my ChordActivity application in a LinearLayout. When a button is clicked, I want the TextToSpeech engine to speak the name of the button clicked ( e.g; Minor 7th ), which is working fine. I also want an animation of the button 'popping out then back' to occur, which I also have working. The problem is that no matter how I arrange the code, the speech happens first, then the animation happens afterward. I want them to happen at the same time. I know that TextToSpeech has its own message queue, so I assumed that if I used a runnable to do the animation, I could get the speech and the animation to happen simultaneously, but it doesn't. I then backed out the runnable and now have the following code. Does anyone have a solution for this? Much Appreciated.

```
private void speakChordMessage(View v) {
        image = (ImageView) v;
        image.startAnimation(animScale);
        chordTTS.playSilence(2000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        chordTTS.speak(str1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        while (chordTTS.isSpeaking()) {
        }
    }
```

animscale.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" >
    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toXScale="1.3"
        android:toYScale="1.25" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to the animation before calling startAnimation, you'll have a callback for

```
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}
```

Animations, not completely unlike the TextToSpeech engine, are added to a queuing system and not executed immediately. If you call chordTTS.speak() in onAnimationStart(), it should greatly reduce the latency you're seeing. From there, you may need to experiment with small delays to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm!

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm! Is there a process for me to give you credit for this on this site?

Comment: @JoeBarry accept his answer as correct by clicking the green check mark underneath the "down" arrow.